# Faster way to delete dataframes in pandas on jupyter?

Tags: python, pandas, memory, delete-file

I want to delete some large dataframes from my python workspace in jupyter notebook to free up memory. The solution I find online is

```
import gc
del df
gc.collect()
```

But this is taking a *lot* of time to run (15m and counting) and as it runs I can see I'm using up more and more memory on my machine. There must be a faster way to drop dataframes from memory...what am I missing?

Comment: Are you using Jupyter?

Comment: Yes, editing question now to clarify that!

Comment: Jupyter won't release the memory.  If you have something this robust, you're better to use and IDE like PyCharm community.  I had a similar issue.  Same script in PyCharm properly released the memory with `del(df)`

Comment: Ok thanks but that's reassuring I'm not the only one with this issue. Unfortunately I'm stuck with jupyter in my current work environment. There must be a solution--this problem seems so unbelievably basic.

Comment: I think it just has to do with how jupyter runs in a browser.  I even did the same things you're doing now with trying `gc`.  I never found a resolution other that to use an IDE.

Comment: give me a clarification please, have you install jupyter notebook using pip or you got it with anaconda distribution?

Comment: We used pip to install jupyter notebooks.